# Basic JQuery Help

Tags: jquery, ajax

Need basic help using JQuery and AJax. I have an ul

```
  <div id="topics">

<h1><a href="index.html">JQuery</a></h1>
  <h3>A Working Primer</h3>

<ul>
    <li><a href="articles/includingJQuery.html">Including JQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="articles/tools.html">Tools of the Trade</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

An empty div where I like the Ajax content to be loaded into on the same page as above:

```
  <div id="articles">
  </div>
```

and my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#topics ul li a").click(function(){
 $('#articles').load('');

 return false; 
   });
});
```

Not exactly sure what to put in the load so its dynamic. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the content is located at the `href` attribute location, then you need to get that attribute's value:

```
$('#articles').load(this.href);
```

so try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#topics ul li a").click(function() {
              // use the content of the href attribute
              //     for the load parameter
        $('#articles').load(this.href);
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick :) I love coming back from lunch and having 5 answers waiting for me, especially when they are pretty much all correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#articles').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

Try that....

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$('#articles').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

would vaguely work, but then you'd end up with the whole remote document loaded in, including duplicate head/body tags.

To get more complex, you could specify a callback function in the .load() and use it to read the returned content, collect only the children of the `<body>` element, and insert those children into your `#articles` element.

Answer (score 0):

This kinda sounds like what you are looking for...  The following function calls a ASP.Net Webservice.  I then use the JSON data returned from the Webservice to append html to my  element.  I think you can probably see from this example what I'm doing and apply it to your own code.  Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        datatype: "json",
        url: "../webServices/myTestWS.asmx/testMethodTV",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            var len = msg.d.rows.length;
            $('#sidetree').append('<ul id="treeview">');
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $('#sidetree').append("<li><span class='expandable'>" + msg.d.rows[i].data + "</span></li>");
            }
            $('#sidetree').append('</ul>');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to structure each included page to have the same div name, such as `#container`, where the data you wanted loaded into the `#articles` div is located. Then you can simply do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#topics ul li a").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#articles').load(url + ' #container');
    return false; 
  });
});
```

This will only fetch the `#container` div and exclude all the extra html/body tags that you don't want and you don't have to deal with callback functions. See http://api.jquery.com/load/